# Background image not showing up in Safari

Tags: html, image, safari, background, png

Any idea why this may not show up in Safari? Sorry, I'm  new to Web development.

```
<img src="images/city.png" class="backgroundImage" alt="San Jose Aerial Drone Photo">
```

Comment: Check the path of the image. Better to put in the full url of the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
.backgroundImage{
    background:url("../images/bg.gif") no-repeat scroll right top #000000;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don’t just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.